# OpenVPN works only with one server?

Tags: openvpn

I have a premium subscription with a website, i could connect to all their 15 servers without any problems and one day everything stopped working, i literally searched for tens of VPN services and tried them none did work.

I have tried all the possible options, tcp & udp,  changing the remote ip and changing the local ip too, nothing works.

All of them would give a handshake error until i found one connection that works, i am going to post the ovpn config content so maybe anyone here can infer or conclude what is the reason that this one works while other doesn't and if there is any solution to his problem, here is the log for the one that works:

```
client

#connect to VPN server
remote 212.98.168.40 443
proto tcp

#DNS server to use
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8

#remove to use your ISP's gateway
redirect-gateway def1

#your access keys
ca in_ca.crt
cert in_2053718.crt
key in_2053718.key
ns-cert-type server

#use virtual interface 'tap'
dev tap

#keep trying indefinitely to resolve the host name of the OpenVPN server.
resolv-retry infinite

#most clients don't need to bind to a specific local port number.
nobind

#try to preserve some state across restarts
persist-key
persist-tun

#enable compression on the VPN link
comp-lzo

#set log file verbosity.
verb 4

#silence repeating messages
mute 20

#Windows specific
win-sys 'env'
route-method exe
route-delay 3
```

Here are many other that doesn't work:

```
client

#connect to VPN server
remote 46.183.221.153 443
proto tcp

#DNS server to use
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8

#remove to use your ISP's gateway
redirect-gateway def1

#your access keys
ca in_ca.crt
cert in_2053718.crt
key in_2053718.key
ns-cert-type server

#use virtual interface 'tap'
dev tap

#keep trying indefinitely to resolve the host name of the OpenVPN server.
resolv-retry infinite

#most clients don't need to bind to a specific local port number.
nobind

#try to preserve some state across restarts
persist-key
persist-tun

#enable compression on the VPN link
comp-lzo

#set log file verbosity.
verb 4

#silence repeating messages
mute 20

#Windows specific
win-sys 'env'
route-method exe
route-delay 3
```

Another one:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 93.115.85.34 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Here is the error i usually recieves when trying to connect to anything other than the first connection i have posted here:

```
Wed Oct 22 11:41:37 2014 us=191000 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occu
r within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed Oct 22 11:41:37 2014 us=191000 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed Oct 22 11:41:37 2014 us=191000 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restar
ting
Wed Oct 22 11:41:37 2014 us=207000 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Wed Oct 22 11:41:37 2014 us=207000 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process res
tarting
Wed Oct 22 11:41:37 2014 us=207000 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

Edit: Lately i have tried SSTP and it seems to work but the problem is that it's extremely slow and while i have a fiber cable its frustrating to download a file at the speed of 200kb/s while i can do it at 11mb/s.

Edit: It seems that there is another option that can make you use vpn in case of extreme censorship which is using STUNNEL (SSL Tunnel), this will wrap the packets and make them look like pure SSL. But again the problem is that it's very slow too.

Comment: It's most probably an issue with your .crt files. You can open them in Windows Explorer and check the expiration dates. If that's okay, ask the service provider why your certificate is no longer valid.

Comment: It's definitely not that as i have tried over 10 services

Answer (score 0):

1. Talk to the website host and see if they have made any configuration changes that would affect your connection (my bet is the problem is here)
2. Check the expiration date on your keys and certs
3. Use a protocol sniffer to see what's happening with your traffic at a lower level. Many times the packets will have detailed information about the error while the console output only gives you generic information.
4. Increase the verbosity of your log files and check those for information.

Comment: None of the above really helped and i tried maximizing the verbosity but the error is stuck at an event that wouldn't return a result.